# Eclipse: Generate Entity from Table

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently facing a problem with the function "generate entities from tables" in eclipse. I try to add a connection to my ms-sql server, but stuck with the following error message: (Define and select a driver from the drop-down list to continue)
[image: Driver connection]

I added the driver correctly, chose it but can not click the next button.
Has anyone an idea why?

Comment: Did you install JDBC driver for SQL server? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Answer (score 0):

After chosing the driver, you should also edit its jar location, clicking by the icon near the driver name.

Comment: As I mentioned I chose the jar file: sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: I tried an other way, with the generic source typ. Now it's possible to ping to my ms sql databases and all db's are listed, but no database schema and tables are there.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand. When you say you selected sqljdbc4.jar, you mean that from "Edit Driver Definition" panel "Jar List" tab you inserted (or browsed for) the full path of the jar file? If not, the driver won't be found.

Comment: Sure, I browsed for it, so that the correct path was inserted.

Comment: I read this post here, what describes exactly my problem with the generic jdbc connection: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=259827

Answer (score 0):

Found it out myself. I used the wrong jar file. Its working with mssql-jdbc-6.2.0.jre8

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the exact same bug today, and here is a workaround that worked for me,

Step 1:

- Go to Window > Preferences > Data Management > Driver Definition
- Create a "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver" with jar file from https://clojars.org/repo/com/microsoft/sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar
  and fill-in the properties
- Create a "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 JDBC Driver" with jar file from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/8.4.1.jre8/mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar
  and fill-in the properties

Step 2:

- Window > Open Perspective > Database Development
- on the left pane, right click Database Connections > New...
- Select SQL Server
- click next
- Choose "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver"
  you should have the "Test Connection" button enabled.
- click on it, test should be ok
- click finish, you're done !